# PostgreSQL login issue, unable to connect in Linux

Tags: postgresql

when I am trying to login to postgresql by using `psql -d root -U postgres` I am getting below error.

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

And when typing only `psql` getting below error:

```
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "[local]", user "root", database "root", SSL off
```

what I can do ? I am not able to undrstand.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:
open pg_hba.conf  file (/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf) and
uncomment or add the line :

```
local all all trust
```

Then restart postgresql

```
# /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to login with user postgres to database root while current user is root?

Your options are:

current user: *root*; desired user: *postgres*; desired database: *root*

in `pg_hba.conf`:`local postgres root   md5`
and execute: `psql -d root -U postgres` and login with your password for postgres

current user: *postgres*; desired user: *postgres*; desired database: *root*

in `pg_hba.conf`: `local postgres root   peer`
and execute `psql -d root`

current user: *root*; desired user: *root*; desired database: *root*

in `pg_hba.conf` `local root root   peer`
and execute `psql`

**Neither to say never to login as root at your database!**